# C3P0 Connection Pool Getting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver exception

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, oracle11g, c3p0

I am using `c3p0` connection pooling in my web application, when i am running the this application i am getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` exception, i used `Datasource.java` class for making the connection pools,  `Utils.java` for reading properties from `datasouce.properties` file.

full Execption is (which i am getting 10 timese) why exception is coming. i am using `odbc6.jar` file for oracle driver, please help me

```
2015-09-07 16:53:32 INFO  AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:527 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 10, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> z8kflt9b1agzamcthrvgf|1d84bc10, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> z8kflt9b1agzamcthrvgf|1d84bc10, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 10, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:LOCALDB, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 200, maxStatements -> 2100, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2015-09-07 16:54:02 WARN  BasicResourcePool:1911 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@295bc68c -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
2015-09-07 16:54:02 WARN  BasicResourcePool:1911 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@78da5318 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
```

**JSP File : -**

```
<%
    Datasource ds = Datasource.getInstance();
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    try{
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from app_userlist");
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    %>
```

**Datasource.java**

```
public class Datasource {       

private Datasource() throws IOException, SQLException {
    // load datasource properties   
    props = Utils.readProperties("datasource.properties");
    cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setJdbcUrl(props.getProperty("jdbcUrl"));
    cpds.setUser(props.getProperty("username"));
    cpds.setPassword(props.getProperty("password"));

    cpds.setInitialPoolSize(new Integer((String) props.getProperty("initialPoolSize")));
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(new Integer((String) props.getProperty("acquireIncrement")));
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(new Integer((String) props.getProperty("maxPoolSize")));
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(new Integer((String) props.getProperty("minPoolSize")));
    cpds.setMaxStatements(new Integer((String) props.getProperty("maxStatements")));

    Connection testConnection = null;
    Statement testStatement = null;

    // test connectivity and initialize pool
    try {
           testConnection = cpds.getConnection();
           testStatement = testConnection.createStatement();
           testStatement.executeQuery("select 1+1 from DUAL");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            testStatement.close();
            testConnection.close();
    }

}

public static Datasource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException {
    if (datasource == null) {
          datasource = new Datasource();
          return datasource;
        } else {
          return datasource;
        }
}

  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      return this.cpds.getConnection();
  } }
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

   static public Properties readProperties(String filename) throws IOException{
      Properties props = new Properties();
      ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
      props.load(stream);
      return props;
   } 
}
```

**datasource.properties:-**

```
driverClass =oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbcUrl =jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:userdb
username =user
password =xxxx                                                 
factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
maxPoolSize="50"   
minPoolSize="15"
acquireIncrement="3"
acquireRetryAttempts = "0"
acquireRetryDelay = "3000"
breakAfterAcquireFailure = "false"
maxConnectionAge = "60"
maxIdleTime = "30"
maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = "10"
idleConnectionTestPeriod = "15"
testConnectionOnCheckout = "true"
preferredTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces = "true"  
autoCommitOnClose="true"
```

Comment: You probably haven't included the Oracle drivers in the classpath.

Comment: i didnt set the driverclass to ComboPooledDataSource object, thanks for your comment @RogerGustavsson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

This exception can have 2 causes:

- The JDBC driver is not loaded at all.
- URL does not match any of the loaded JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 4):

**DRIVER CLASS:** oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

**DRIVER LOCATION:** Simply specify the location of the jar or zip file that contains the Oracle Thin drivers.

**JDBC URL FORMAT:** 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:/ServiceName 
or
jdbc:oracle:thin:@::

**NOTE:** The Oracle thin driver requires the SID or ServiceName of the database in the JDBC URL as opposed to the database alias. Consult your Oracle documentation for more details.

**JDBC URL Examples:**

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@neptune.acme.com:1521:T10A

jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:T10A